# Obtener el elemento máximo de un array y posición

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy iniciándome en JavaScript y estoy en el tema de los arreglos.

Ingresando los elementos del array mediante los inputs debo obtener el elemento máximo y su posición.

Esto lo que he intentado:

```js
function Calculate() {
  var array1 = document.form.elements["array"];
  var max = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i].value == null) {
      array1[i].value = 0;
    }
    document.write(array1[i].value + " ");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (max < array1[i].value) {
      max = array1[i].value;
    }
  }
  document.write("<br>El máximo elemento es: " + max);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form name="form" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Escribe los elementos del arreglo:</th>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="11"><input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="Calculate()" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Cuando ingreso un número de dos cifras en adelante no lo toma en cuenta y calcula el máximo solo de los números de una cifra es decir del 1 al 9.

También quisiera saber como puedo llenar de ceros en las posiciones de los inputs vacíos al imprimir el array. Y como puedo imprimir los resultados en la misma página ya que al hacer click se limpia y después imprime los resultados.

Comment: si te guarda todos los elementos?  imprime tu arreglo para ver si van todos tus valores que ingresaste en los input con console.log(nombreArreglo)

Comment: con esta funcion encuentras el maximo Math.max()

Comment: aqui tienes para el minimo Math.min(1, 2, 3, 4); // 1

Comment: @Rubén te comento que hice la prueba y tiene errores como comenta Neon, ingresé diversas cantidades con doble números y el máximo me marcó "9", te dejo los datos que ingresé (43 1 4 54 32 5 2 9 87 57 ).

Comment: Creé un html exactamente como lo colocó @Neon e ingresé los datos que te mencioné.

Comment: Has planteado **tres preguntas en una**, lo cual no es acorde con Stackoverflow. Para poder obtener una respuesta adecuada a cada duda, sería mejor que las plantees por separado, una vez hayas investigado si no hay preguntas que ya respondan a tus dudas. Gracias.

Comment: parsea en la comparación a `int parseInt()`  o `float parseFloat`   `if (max < parseFloat(array1[i].value))`  haber como va

Comment: @Rubén intenta cambiar el "99" por un número de dos dígitos y cambia uno por un "9" (1 2 3 66 1 2 3 4 8 9)

Comment: @Rubén perdón por mi primer comentario, el punto es que debes remover el 99 ya que ese si lo toma como número más alto. En cuanto a lo que comentas de la pregunta yo te apoyo, ya que está mal formulada.

Comment: @BDOM Eliminé mi respuesta y comentarios sobre la misma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la rutina evalúa alfabéticamente y debe hacerlo numéricamente para que pueda dar el resultado esperado, en el siguiente ejemplo te muestro como hacer para convertir un **cadena alfanumérica** `String` a **numero entero** `Integer` ademas de como imprimir el resultado sin borrar la pagina.

Ejemplo:

```js
function Calculate() {
  var array1 = document.form.elements["array"];
  var max = 0;
  var r = "",pos=0;

  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(array1[i].value) || !array1[i].value) {
      array1[i].value = "0";
    }
    r+=parseInt(array1[i].value,10) + " ";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (max < parseInt(array1[i].value,10)) {
      max = parseInt(array1[i].value,10),pos = i;
    }
  }
  r+="<br>El máximo elemento es: " + max+ " en la posicion: "+(pos+1);
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=r;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form name="form" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Введите элементы массива:</th>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="array" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="11"><input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="Calculate()" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
```